# Advice on my Transformer

Tags: transformer, diy

Background: I need a transformer that can supply 6.3V (+/-1%, as per the heater's specs) and 25 A for a heater.

As a result, I decided to hack a MOT by breaking off the bottom laminations and removing the coils.

The plan is to use a variac (0-130 VAC, 1 kW max.) that will plug into a US standard single phase outlet (110-120 VAC, 50/60 Hz). The output of the variac will lead to the primary windings of the MOT.

For reference, the MOT core has a depth of 2 inches, a width of 3.5 inches, and a height of 3 inches.

For my application, I rewound the MOT such that the primary is made up of 17 turns of 18 AWG wire insulated for 300 VAC. The secondary is comprised of a single turn of 8 AWG wire. Both the primary and the secondary take up an equal length of the MOT core.

Since the bottom of the core was broken off, it is currently a bit loose but is attached to the rest of the core via gravity.

I used a zip tie to provide a 1 cm gap between the primary and secondary windings.

Here are a few pictures of the set up for reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Question: Will this set up allow for me to produce a sufficient voltage (assuming I set the variac to around 107 VAC) and 25-30 A?

Comment: your heater seems remarkably fussy about supply voltage

Comment: this kind of thing makes me nervous. Trying to hack a 25A 6V supply with what appears to be normal insulated wire? Have you considered the possibility that, should you actually get it going, you might end up with melting insulation, and possibly disastrous results? I hope you have good quality breakers and a fire extinguisher handy.

Answer (score 1):

no, that setup will not produce enough voltage (at mains frequency)

at mains frequency microwave oven transformers saturate at about 1 turn per volt,
so you want a secondary with more than 6 turns.

Put the original primary back onto your transformer, and add 7 to 10 turns of thick copper wire, or magnet-wire "rope" for the secondary

Comment: Would the secondary wires for a MOT be able to handle the 25 A current? Thank you.

Comment: if you twist many strands in parallel to make a rope it would be able to carry 25A, be sure that the ends of each strand are fully soldered

Comment: Is it acceptable for bare copper wires carrying 6.3 V to be in contact with each other in the secondary? The insulation may be too thick for my MOT. I'm planning to wrap it with electrical tape, but there might be some copper wiring that finds its way to another strand.

Comment: bare wirwes must be insulated (must not touch), the wires used in the original secondary have a clear insulating coating on them,  this type of wire is called "magnet wire"

Comment: thats only for contact between turns of the secondary, it's ok to use stranded wire for the secondary so long as each turn of the secondary is insulated from the other turns.

Comment: Will normal 8 AWG copper wire work for the secondary? Thank you

Comment: Moreover, would I be able to change to a 24:7 winding, where the 300v 18 AWG wire makes up the primary and the 7 turns come from the 8 AWG copper wires on the secondary? Due to the number of turns, the primary will also likely have wires layered on top of other wires.

Comment: http://www.magnetwire.biz/magnet_wire_current.html only good for 24A use two in parralel.

Comment: Unfortunately my transformer is relatively urgent and I don't think that I'll have enough time to get it shipped. Would the 8 AWG copper wire on the secondary allow me to produce the needed 6.3 V and 25 A? Thank you.

Comment: magnet wire is preferred becase its insulation can handle higher temperature than PVC insulated wire. and because it's more compact

Comment: Would the temperature issue be resolved by a cooling fan? At least enough so that I could get away with using electrical tape for insulation on the 8 AWG copper wiring. Thank you.

Comment: unwind the secondary an put several strands in parallel to make a rope with about 10 square millimeter total cross section.  that's about approximately  a square with 1/8"  sides

Comment: Sounds good. Would I be able to use electrical tape to insulate them, or should I be using something different.

Comment: put electrical tape, or (trasformer paper if you have it)  on the core to prevent damage to the insulation on the magnet wire, it ir easily scratched,